# How to output my results all the way at the end of my program versus at the end of each iteration?

Tags: c

So my program takes a string, and then outputs it as a marquee sign. I have a for loop so that it may take multiple strings and then outputs each of the strings as a sign.

My problem is: after each iteration, it outputs the sign, and then continues to prompt me for the next string when I want it to just take in all my inputs at once, and then output every sign at the very end. Here is what I'm talking about:

```
Current Input:
3
Hello World!
5
Sign #1: (This is the output)
[Hello]
[ello ]
[llo W]
[lo Wo]
[o Wor]
[ Worl]
[World]
[orld!]
[rld! ]
[ld! H]
[d! He]
[! Hel]
[ Hell]
Activist
10
Sign #2: (This is the output)
[Activist  ]
LOL
2
Sign #3: (This is the output)
[LO]
[OL]
[L ]
[ L]
```

This is what I want it to do:

```
Input:
3
Hello World!
5
Activist
10
LOL
2 
Output:
Sign #1: 
[Hello]
[ello ]
[llo W]
[lo Wo]
[o Wor]
[ Worl]
[World]
[orld!]
[rld! ]
[ld! H]
[d! He]
[! Hel]
[ Hell]

Sign #2:
[Activist  ]

Sign #3:
[LO]
[OL]
[L ]
[ L]
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void ignoreRestOfLine(FILE *fp) {
    int c;
    while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF && c != '\n');
}

int main() {
    int num_times, count = 0;
    int marq_length, sign = 0;
    scanf("%d ", &num_times);
    char s[100];

    for (count = 0; count < num_times; count++) {
        if (fgets(s, sizeof(s), stdin) == NULL) {
            // Deal with error.
        }
        if (scanf("%d", &marq_length) != 1) {
            // Deal with error.
        }
        ignoreRestOfLine(stdin);

        size_t n = strlen(s) - 1;
        int i, j;

        if (s[strlen(s)-1] == '\n')
            s[strlen(s)-1] = '\0';

        printf("Sign #%d:\n", ++sign);

        if (n <= marq_length) {
            printf("[%-*s]\n", marq_length, s);
        } else {
            for (i = 0; i < n + 1; i++) {
                putchar('[');
                for (j = 0; j < marq_length; j++) {
                    char c = s[(i + j) % (n + 1)];
                    if (!c)
                        c = ' ';
                    putchar(c);
                }
                printf("]\n");
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "_So my program_" -- Is it really [your program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35678399/how-to-output-a-marquee-string-that-is-smaller-than-the-size-of-the-marquee-sign)? Or do you have multiple accounts?

Comment: You must learn to indent your code properly.  It is a pain to re-indent from your post and the previous ones, but necessary to make it readable.

Comment: @CoolGuy I have multiple accounts so i don't have to wait 90 minutes to post consecutive questions. is there a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the program logic: parse all the inputs into arrays and perform the tasks in a second phase.  It will be a bit tedious to change the code.

a simpler solution is to put all your inputs into a text file and use shell redirection to read the input from the text file.  All the outputs will appear at once.

Comment: thank you. i will try this approach! sorry for the messy indentation