# Scroll a word through an array in C from right to left?

Tags: c, arrays

Lets say you have (can be any length string).

```
char word[] = "Coding is really fun";
```

And some empty "buffer" array that has a 10 character limit.

```
char buffer[12] = "            "; //initialized with 10 spaces, leaving room for null character.
```

For example, after the first pass `buffer` would be            "         C"; (9 spaces in front of C)

Then next "         Co"; (8 spaces in front)

The code below works to an extent, but when it gets to larger values of i, it starts adding multiple characters and then repeatedly adding the first character over and over again.

```
int i = 0;
int j;
int k = 0;
char word[] = "Coding is really fun";
char buffer[12] = "            ";
buffer[11]='\0';
buffer[10] = word[0];

while(1){
k = 0;
for (j = 10 - i; j < 11; j++){
    buffer[j] = word[k];
    k++;
}
i++;
}
```

Eventually I want to scroll through `word` until it passes all the way through `buffer` and then the buffer is empty again.

I know my issue, it is my for-loop. When I exceed the size of the buffer (i is the variable I am using to keep track of what character I need to add to the buffer next), i exceeds 10. Then I start running into issues. How can I rewrite this so that `word` essentially "slides" through `buffer`, from right to left?

This is exactly what I want to do, to try and explain it further. Assume we have

```
char word[] = "Hello"; 
char buffer[4] = "   " //space for 3 characters.

After the first pass through the loop, buffer should be "  H"
After the second pass through the loop, buffer should be " He"
After the third pass through the loop, buffer should be "Hel"
After the fourth pass through the loop, buffer should be "ell"
After the fifth pass through the loop, buffer should be "llo"
After the sixth pass, buffer should be "lo "
After the seventh, buffer should be "o  "
After the eighth, buffer should be "   " (empty once again).
```

Comment: This is not `c` syntax. What language are you really using?

Comment: `char[12] buffer;buffer = "    "` is not valid C, your compiler should have given you an error message.

Comment: *Any thoughts?* - is not a valid question.

Comment: Please post the working code that you have, and also tag this question with the correct language tag.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield Code is now posted, and the language is C, that is what I tagged.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Question clarified.

Comment: @chux My code is posted

Comment: @Citut I still don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Pablo I'll edit now with exactly what I want my result to do.

Comment: @Citut: If you want a sliding window over a string, you have to maintain the relative position of the window against the length of the string. You don't want to include the null terminator in the window (well, usually not, anyways).

Comment: @Pablo Look at bottom of post to see exactly what I am talking about.

Comment: See [How to output a marquee string that is smaller than the size of the marquee sign?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35678399/) . If it isn't an exact duplicate, it is certainly closely related.  You can find what I coded as an (unsubmitted) answer on GitHub in my [SOQ](https://github.com/jleffler/soq) (Stack Overflow Questions) repository in the
[src/so-3567-8399](https://github.com/jleffler/soq/tree/master/src/so-3567-8399) sub-directory.

Comment: One way to implement this is that slide a sliding window (of size of buffer) through 'word'  array of and print it in 'buffer' at every iteration. For out of bound indexes of 'word' array print '\0' in buffer. At every iteration output buffer to console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine that you have a circular source text that consists of your `word` followed by as many spaces as your buffer. The size of this imaginary circular source text is

```
size_t wordsize = strlen(word);
size_t buffsize = strlen(buffer);
size_t icstsize = wordsize + buffsize;
```

Each time you shift the buffer you change each character in it. The first section of the text is shifted left, and the last character is taken from the imaginary circular source text. Let's keep track of the position in the imaginary circular source text:

```
size_t position = 0; // start at character zero of word
```

Now

```
while (1)
{
    // shift the buffer
    for (size_t i = 0u; i < (buffsize - 1u); i++)
        buffer[i] = buffer[i + 1u];
    // fill in the last character
    buffer[buffsize - 1u] = position < wordsize ? word[position] : ' ';
    // increment the position in the imaginary circular source text 
    position = (position + 1u) % icstsize;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Doug Currie**'s code really works awesome, just tested.
Compiled with: `gcc -Wall shift_buffer.c -std=c11`

here is his code ready to test (JUST TO EASE UP TESTING):
**Again, this is his code**.

```
#define _BSD_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
        char word[] = "Coding is really fun";
        char buffer[12] = "            "; //initialized with 10 spaces, leaving room for null character.

        size_t wordsize = strlen(word);
        size_t buffsize = strlen(buffer);
        size_t icstsize = wordsize + buffsize;

        size_t position = 0; // start at character zero of word

        while (1)
        {
                // shift the buffer
                for (size_t i = 0u; i < (buffsize - 1u); i++)
                        buffer[i] = buffer[i + 1u];

                // fill in the last character
                buffer[buffsize - 1u] = position < wordsize ? word[position] : ' ';

                // increment the position in the imaginary circular source text
                position = (position + 1u) % icstsize;
                fprintf(stderr, "[%s] \r", buffer);
                usleep(500000);
        }

}
```